# Script, app or utility to create google accounts for testing

Tags: google-account

I have a very frequent test scenario that requires a new Google account every run.

Is there anything that can automate Google account creation like a script or utility or perhaps even an Android app of some sort?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with some automation tools to automate browsers and create new accounts. Some tools may be helpful:

1. Microsoft Excel (Automate browser using VBA)
2. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/
3. https://www.macrorecorder.com/
4. https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/

A lot more tools are available on the web. Test few tools to find the one that fits your needs.